# How I can count a a non-numeric value in R?

Tags: r, vector, count, letters

I have a vector of letters:

```
v <- c("M", "W", "M", "M", "M", "W", "M", "X", "X", "M", "X", "M", 
"M", "M", "W")
```

How can I have R count the letters in the vector?

Like:

```
M 9 
W 3
X 3
```

Comment: See `?table`. `table(v)` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, thx <3 never saw that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `table()` function.

```
> table(v)
v
M W X 
9 3 3
```